# c# how can I sidestep the memory allocation bottleneck to improve multithreading performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, memory-management, heap-memory

I use C# as a research tool, and frequently need to run CPU intensive tasks such as optimisations.  In theory I should be able to get big performance improvements by multi-threading my code, but in practice when I use the same number of threads as the number of cores available on my workstation I usually find that the CPU is still only running at 25%-50% of max.  Interrupting the code to see what all the threads are doing strongly suggests that memory allocation is the bottleneck, because most threads will be waiting for `new` statements to execute.

One solution would be to try and re-engineer all my code to be much more memory efficient, but that would be a big and time-consuming task.  However, since I have an abundance of memory on my workstation, I'm wondering if I can sidestep this problem by setting up the different threads so that they each have their own private pool of memory to work from.  Of course, some objects will still need to be public between all threads, otherwise it won't be possible to specify the tasks for each thread or to harvest the results.

Does anyone know if this kind of approach is possible in C#, and if so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Memory management is done by .Net framework, and there is not much you can do. However, are you really sure that the bottleneck is not in IO or other subsystem?

Comment: @oscar yes I'm as as sure as I can be that it's the memory management, because I set up optimisation problems were all data is held in memory, so none of my threads need to do any IO whatsoever.  It's also plausible, given that there is just one heap from which to create all the objects.

Comment: You have a lot of memory and build x64 and still have allocation as bottleneck? What kind of memory usage you are seeing/ expecting?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes I use x64 with Windows 7, because I often used to get `OutOfMemoryException` running x86.  Languages like C# which do all the memory allocation for the programmer encourage programmers to focus higher level goals, instead of low level memory management efficiency.  But if there's only one heap for allocating new objects, that could clearly be a multithreading bottleneck, and indeed when I interrupt my code there are a lot of pending `new` statements.

Comment: Do you really need most of the data to be on the heap, or is it acceptable to allocate them on the stack? If the latter is the case, using structs instead of classes could yield some speedup.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis are you saying that "new struct()" gets allocated on the stack, whereas "new class()" gets allocated on the global heap?  If so, I didn't know that, so indeed it might help.  But the purpose of asking this question was to try and find out if it's possible to force C# to use different global heaps in different situations, which for me would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @Stochastically It's a little more complicated than that. It's more along the lines of "if the compiler can prove that the reference doesn't escape the scope, it will usually allocate on the stack". This applies for both classes and structs - it simply depends on the actual usage of the object. The difference is that since struct variables pass the data itself (instead of a reference), they are much more likely to meet the criteria for stack allocation. (Though keep in mind that this whole thing is implementation dependent, since the stack and the heap themselves *are* implementation details.)

Comment: @Stochastically There are also `unsafe` blocks where you can use `stackalloc` and have explicit control over where the allocation happens (but it applies only for struct instances, not class instances). It's true that it's not a very clean solution, especially if it gets in the way of the semantics of your code, that's why I made it a comment. It might help you out as a last resort, though.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis (Correction to my earlier comment: class references are never allocated on the stack. What I mentioned applies only for structs.)

Answer (score 6):

If you has memory allocation bottleneck, you should:

1. Use "objects pool" (as @MartinJames said). Initialize objects pool, when application is started. Objects pool should improve performance of heap allocation.
2. Use structs (or any value type), as local variables, because stack allocation is much faster than heap.
3. Avoid implicit memory allocation. For example, when you add item into `List<>`:

   > If Count already equals Capacity, the capacity of the List is
   >   increased by **automatically reallocating the internal array**, and the
   >   existing elements are copied to the new array before the new element
   >   is added (source MSDN).
4. Avoid boxing. It's very expensive:

   > In relation to simple assignments, boxing and unboxing are
   >   computationally expensive processes. When a value type is boxed, a new
   >   object must **be allocated and constructed**. To a lesser degree, the cast
   >   required for unboxing is also expensive computationally. (source MSDN)
5. Avoid lambda expressions which captures a variable (because new object will be created for captured variable)

Answer (score 1):

That is similar to what I do in servers - use object pools for freqently-used classes, (though not in C#).

I guess that, in C#, you could use a BlockingCollection. Prefill it with a load of T's and Take() objects from it, use them and then return with Add().

This works well with objects that are numerous and large, (eg. server data buffers), or have complex and lengthy ctors/dtors, (eg. an http receiver/parser component) - popping/pushing such objects, ('cos essentially pointers in NET), off/on queues is much quicker than continually creating them and later having the GC destroy them.

NOTE: an object popped from such a pool queue has probably been used before and may need some explicit initialization!

Comment: Thanks @MartinJames, in fact I have have now implemented that kind of idea in some of my code, but it suddenly struck me that if it was possible to force C# to use different memory heaps in different situations then that would be much more convenient.

Comment: Some convenience can be built-in :)  All my pooled objects derive from a base class that has a 'Pool myPool' private member and a parameterless 'release()' method that pushes the object back on - no need to pass the pool instance around and no chance of pushing the object back onto the wrong pool. The problem with private heaps is, as you know, inter-thread comms: if you queue an object that is allocated from a private pool to another thread, a pool lock is required to delete it, so defeating the advantages of a private heap.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a particularly a C# or .NET problem. For a CPU core to run optimally it needs all its data to be in the CPU cache. If a particular data is not in the CPU cache, a cache fault happens and CPU sit idle until the data is fetched from memory to Cache.

If your in memory data is too much fragmented the chance of Cache fault increases.

The way CLR does heap allocation is much more optimal for CPU cache. Its unlikely that you can achieve the same performance by handling the memory allocation yourself.

Comment: I'm not looking to handle the allocation myself. I just want to be able to instruct C# to have multiple memory heaps so that different threads don't need to wait for each other when I create new objects.